# Number of combinations/permutations

Tags: rust, combinatorics

How do I find the number of permutations or combinations in rust?

E.g. [`C(10,6) = 210`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%2810%2C6%29)

I can't find this function in the standard library, nor can I find the factorial operator there (which would suffice).

Comment: Note, I am not looking for a crate, though a comment pointing to a crate would still be nice, e.g. [factorial crate](https://docs.rs/factorial/0.2.0/factorial/trait.Factorial.html)

Comment: Don't forget [`(1..=n).product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building off @vallentin's answer, there are many optimizations that could be made. Let's use the same factorial function (for now):

```rust
fn factorial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..=n).product()
}
```

For `count_permutations`, `n! / (n - r)!` is actually just the product of all numbers between `n - r + 1` and `n` (inclusive), so we don't even need to compute 2 factorials (which could overflow and involve computing the product of overlapping numbers):

```rust
fn count_permutations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    (n - r + 1..=n).product()
}
```

We can do a similar optimization for `count_combinations`:

```
fn count_combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    (n - r + 1..=n).product::<u64>() / factorial(r)
}
```

`count_permutations` is pretty much completely optimized, being both fast and correct (if the result of `count_permutations` can fit in a `u64` then it should never overflow).

`count_combinations` still has a couple flaws, namely that since it's computing a product then dividing, its result could fit in a `u64`, but the function will still overflow. You can make it pretty close to non-overflowing with alternating multiplication and division:

```rust
fn count_combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    if r > n {
        0
    } else {
        (1..=r).fold(1, |acc, val| acc * (n - val + 1) / val)
    }
}
```

Putting it all together:

```rust
fn count_combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    if r > n {
        0
    } else {
        (1..=r).fold(1, |acc, val| acc * (n - val + 1) / val)
    }
}

fn count_permutations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    (n - r + 1..=n).product()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", count_combinations(10, 6));
    println!("{}", count_permutations(10, 6));
}
```

Note that there are some micro-optimizations that you can do, namely going to `r.min(n - r)` instead of `r` for `count_combinations`, since `count_combinations(n, r) == count_combinations(n, n - r)`, and going to the smaller of the two will shrink the loop size:

```rust
fn count_combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    if r > n {
        0
    } else {
        (1..=r.min(n - r)).fold(1, |acc, val| acc * (n - val + 1) / val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the alternations create integers division rounding, making it inaccurate?

Comment: @PunkyMunky64 It's guaranteed that by the time you divide by `val`, it will be a factor of the current accumulator, so there's no inaccuracy (that's why you multiply from largest to smallest but divide from smallest to largest)

Answer (score 3):

The standard library doesn't include any operator or function for calculating the factorial of a number.

Instead you can use the [`factorial` crate](https://crates.io/crates/factorial) or you could use the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num), which the [Rust Cookbook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/science/mathematics/miscellaneous.html) includes an example of. Here's a variation of the Rust Cookbook example, without using the `num` crate.

```rust
fn factorial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut f = 1;
    for i in 1..=n {
        f *= i;
    }
    f
}
```

As already [commented by L. F.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561566/number-of-combinations-permutations-in-rust/65561835#comment115913592_65561566), this could be expressed shorter using [`product()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product), which the documentation for `product()` includes an example of.

```rust
fn factorial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..=n).product()
}
```

---

The standard library also doesn't have functions for calculating the number of permutations or combinations a given `n` and `r` would give. Instead you can just translate the formulas into functions, like this:

```rust
/// n! / (r! * (n - r)!)
fn count_combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r))
}

/// n! / (n - r)!
fn count_permutations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    factorial(n) / factorial(n - r)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", count_combinations(10, 6)); // Prints `210`
    println!("{}", count_permutations(10, 6)); // Prints `151200`
}
```

If you actually want to produce permutations and/or combinations, then you could use the [`itertools` crate](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) and specifically use the [`permutations()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.permutations) and [`combinations()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations) functions.